# how to store number of second in variable in java

Tags: java, long-integer

I want to generate a token(validity in second) for 20 years. So total numbers of second in 20 years are: 631152000. Here is a token generation code:

```
    long tokenLifetInSecond=631152000;
    long expiryTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    expiryTime += 1000L * tokenLifetimeInSecond;
```

So the result of expiryTime=2095766040489. Is using long is a safe as it can store 2 billion records ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of system are you working on that requires "tokens" valid for 20 years?

Comment: Well token will use in a stand alone terminals to access some service. In simple i want to generate a life time token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long.MAX_VALUE : 9223372036854775807

Comment: it's my pleasure , yeah it can

Answer (score 0):

You can use Big Integer in java or store this value in String.

Comment: well API required to give value in long.

Answer (score 0):

The largest value representable by as a `long` is:

9,223,372,036,854,775,808

Now `tokenLifetimeInSeconds` is

631,152,000

and in milliseconds that is

631,152,000,000

which will easily fit into a `long`.  Your supplied value

2,095,766,040,489

Will do as well.

I would say that your token encode scheme is going to be OK.  In fact, your code is likely to be fine until the year 292,277,026,576 AD.

Reference:

- http://ximalas.info/2015/03/10/when-does-the-64-bit-unix-time_t-really-end/

Comment: Thanks a lot for more clarification. I forgot where i read long limit is 2 billion or store upto 2 billion so that confused. Thanks everyone

Comment: @user526206 - The ~2 billion limit is for 32 bit signed integers; i.e. `int` in Java.

Comment: Very interesting. Token expiry checked by spring security hope they have something to avoid this. I will check the source code.

Comment: Actually, I think I have confused the expiry time for the actual token.